# Sleep certain sections of the script

Tags: shell, sleep

I want to pause/sleep the elif part but keep the other elif parts working . I don't want the whole script to sleep if 1 sensor goes off.

```
#!/bin/sh

while true;  do
    valid=""


    scan=`./script`

    if [ "$scan" = "$valid" ]; then
        echo "Good value"

    else
        echo "Bad value"

    fi

    sleep 5
done

exit
```

So if 1 sensor is triggered it waits for a couple seconds before sending a pushbullet alert for that 1 sensor , but it doesn't cause other sensors to stop sending alerts if the 1 sensor is delayed.

I don't want to be informed every time a sensor goes off I want their to be a delay so it doesn't keep sending me alerts.

Comment: Why isn't it required?

Comment: @securitytestman Regarding the '..doesn't sleep the other elif statement..' part from your question. The elif blocks are read sequentially, so there is no parallel operation happening there.

Comment: Haxiel does this mean if I want them to act as different parts of the script I will need to use something other than elif?

Comment: @securitytestman Please use the '@username' notation when you reply, so that I can get a notification for your comment. As for your question, the answer is yes. If you want to run different blocks of code in parallel, you'll need more advanced tools.

Comment: Is it intentional that `echo "Good Read"; echo "Your code is " $scan` is only executed for the door bell?

Comment: And unless the `curl`s take a long time there is probably not really a need to kick them off into the background.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#again you must use bash... 
valid[0]=160650648 ; valid[1]=163686025
valid[2]=120806542 ; valid[3]=37206841
i=0

while sleep 5;  do
    scan=$(./RFSniffer)
    if [ "$scan" == "$oldscan" ]; then
    i=$((i+1))
    #if i is minor than 10 restart loop...
    #So a alert will not be displayed again after 50 seconds...
        if [ "$i" -lt "10" ]; then
            continue
        else 
            i=0
        fi
    fi

    case $scan in 
           ${valid[0]})
               echo "Good Read"
               echo "Your code is " $scan
               ./buzzer.sh &
               omxplayer -o local sleighbells.mp3
               curl -u "code": https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes -d type=note -d title="Alert" -d body="DoorBell" &
            ;; 
            ${valid[1]})
                curl -u "code": https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes -d type=note -d title="Alert" -d body="front sensor" &
            ;;
            ${valid[2]})
                curl -u "code": https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes -d type=note -d title="Alert" -d body="Back door sensor" &
            ;;
            ${valid[3]})
                curl -u "code": https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes -d type=note -d title="Alert" -d body="Second sensor" &
            ;;
            *)
               echo "BAD READ:  your code and the valid don't match"
               echo "Your correct valid code should be " $scan
            ;;
    esac

    oldscan=$scan
    scan=''
    #sleep 5 not needed sleep 5 is in while condition 

done
```

EDIT: see comments..

Comment: Ops missing a quote... Try again.

Comment: A important question? Do you want to make all the conditions to be hit?  Even if one of them are true?

Comment: Well I want their to be a delay if true 2 is a sensor and I keep moving it goes off every 5 seconds which is very annoying. I want their to be a delay before sending me an alert.

Comment: You want to check all the conditions again after 5 seconds? All the conditions must be checked even if one of them are true? what is your native language? I am a brazilian speaker (brazil native language is portuguese) maybe I can try to understand you in your other language if it is derivated from latin.

Comment: So basically the script is looking out for a signal for a motion sensor. If I was to move near the sensor it will keep sending alerts every 5 seconds I only want alerts to send out every minute or so but still let me know if any other sensors are triggered within that minute (they also need  a delay). Does that sense?

Comment: Look now. It is something like that you want?

Comment: Yeah I only want it to send me an alert every 1 minute if the sensor went off (per sensor)

Comment: So it is right now? This temp file will act as "sensor"... whatever that means... if you want better help show me how this sensor are changed.

Comment: I have updated first post with my current script to help.

Comment: First of all your hashbang is incorrect sh is different from bash. Change it to bash, because you specify in your answer that you are using bash. Bash can have big differences from sh. I will put a answer as soon as i can.

Comment: Thank you it is an .sh file on raspberry pi so should it be sh?

Comment: No the extension doesn't matter if you have bash installed. It should be bash because i write it thinking of bash. If it is GNU/Linux BASH should be better... i updated the code again. I never tested it so let me know if it is doing what you want? If you have only sh in that system let me know.

Comment: new update i=0 in the wrong place...

Comment: Worked for a about 10 minutes then just stopped altogether.

Comment: Permission error had to place on 777.I want the doorbell to be excluded from this list though whats the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct when paraphrasing "The script should independently deliver the scans read but block each scan after occurrence for one minute"?

Your script has some opportunities to simplify / optimize, and I'm assuming you're using `bash` (hoppla - `bash` tag edited away...?) despite the shebang indicating other... So while implementing the one minute pause for the individual scans, I tried also to reap the opportunities (using `echo` for the commands not installed on my system - remove if happy with the operation). Try this and feel free to adapt:

```
VALID=(160650648 163686025 120806542 37206841)                          # define valid scans
BODY=(DoorBell "front sensor" "Back door sensor" "Second sensor")       # define body tests

while true
  do    scan=$(./RFSniffer)

        for IX in "${!VALID[@]}" "${#VALID[@]}"                         # 0 - 3 elements, and 4 to identify bad reads
          do    if [ "${scan:-FALSE}" = "${VALID[IX]}" ]                # compare 4 elements, the 5. tries to compare to "" empty
                  then  echo "Good Read"
                        echo "Your code is " $scan

                        if (( $SECONDS > ${LAST[IX]} + 60 ))            # test for one minute pause
                          then  if [ "$IX" = 0 ]                        # do this just for the "door bell"
                                  then  echo ./buzzer.sh
                                        echo omxplayer -o local sleighbells.mp3
                                fi

                                echo curl -u "code": https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes -d type=note -d title="Alert" -d body="${BODY[IX]}" # &

                                LAST[IX]=$SECONDS                       # keep last scan occurrence
                          else  echo "pausing "                         
                        fi

                        break                                           # if good read - break out of the for loop to avoid the bad read msg
                fi

                if [ "$IX" = "${#VALID[@]}" ]                           # the fifth loop means no valid scan found

                  then  echo "BAD READ:  your code $scan and the valid ones don't match"
                        echo "Your correct valid code should be one of ${VALID[@]}"
                fi
          done

        sleep 5
  done
```

Comment: Well if sensor 1 was set off I would like it to only be able to send 1 alert within a period of a minute or so, but not stop the those other sensors from sending alerts whilst sensor 1 is paused from sending alerts.

Comment: This is exactly what I was targeting at with above. Did you agree to my paraphrase? Did you try the code?

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately doesn't pause, it also doesn't send the alert through pushbullet either.

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't really help identifying errors. It worked for me when I did a `read scan` in lieu of the `RFsniffer`; it `echo`ed the relevant commands once, and then paused for a minute, per valid scan. Did you remove the `echo` from the pushbullet command?